# How to fill a d3 pie using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have a simple pie, the issue im having is that if i pass `[100, 100]` only half of the pie gets full

i want the `#00c2b9` color to occupy the entire pie when i pass in 100, 100

```js
setPie();

function setPie(obj) {
  var id    = '#chart';
  var w     = 55;
  var h     = 55;
  var r     = Math.min(w, h) / 2;
  var color = ["#00c2b9", "#000000"];
  var vis   = d3.select(id).append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
  
  vis.data([[{"value": 90}, {"value":100}]]);
  
  var pie  = d3.layout.pie().value(function (d) {return d.value;});
  var arc  = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);
  var arcs = vis.selectAll("path").data(pie).enter();

  arcs.append("path").attr("fill", function (d, i) {
    return color[i];
  }).attr("d", function (d) {
    return arc(d);
  }).style("opacity", 0.5);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: If the values are equal then it will be shared equally. You need to set one as `0`.

Comment: @anpsmn can u give an example pls

Comment: To get the desired output you can do somthing like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wgtsyr59/) but it doesn't portray both values being 100, 100. So you may need to think if pie chart is the right choice for this.

Comment: the idea is to have 0 start at the top and then 10, 20, 30, .... to reveal the dark side bit by bit

Comment: Ok, then you can use 0 for one. As the percentages are calculated by adding the two numbers as total so when 100,100 is used the total is 200 so 100/200 50% each.

Comment: weird, if i use `100` for the first value and `(50 / 1.5) * -1` then i get the right proportions, but i don't know what `1.5` means :)

Comment: (50 / 1.5) * -1 is negative number, of course it will not be displayed